# Knockout-kendo.js DropDown in Grid Cell

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

Is there an appropriate way to integrate a kendo-ui dropdown in a column of kendo-ui grid?

Here is what I had tried using rniemeyer's [Knockout-kendo.js](http://rniemeyer.github.com/knockout-kendo/web/Grid.html).
Inside $(document).ready:

```
function statusDropDownEditor(container, options) {
         $('<input data-text-field="name" data-value-field="id" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
             .appendTo(container)
             .kendoDropDownList({
                 autoBind: false,
                 dataSource: {
                     transport: {
                         read: "/api/Status"
                     }
                 }
             });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="prod-grid" data-bind="kendoGrid: { data: Products, height: 480,
    sortable: true, selectable: 'row', scrollable: true, resizable: true, pageable: false,
    columns: [ 
    { field: 'ProdName', title : 'Product Name'}, 
    { field: 'UnitCost', title: 'Unit Cost'}, 
    { field: 'TotalAmt', title: 'Batch Total'},
    { field: 'Manufacturer', title: 'Manufacturer'},
    { title: 'Status', editor: statusDropDownEditor}
}>
</div>
```

However, it'll produce an error that says: 
*Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: categoryDropDownEditor is not defined;*

Also, I hope to have the dropdown display the status value based on the Products model.

Comment: I would suggest that you do not define your `kendoGrid` inline with your HTML in the binding. IMO this is bad practice. It can lead to all sorts of problems. Keep your code and markup separate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use knockout kendo's use template option. Here is how you can do it

```
<script id='rowTemplate' type='text/html'>
    <tr> <td> <span data-bind = "text:ProdName" > </span>        </td> 
        <td> <span data-bind = "text:UnitCost" > </span>        </td>
        <td> <span data-bind = "text:TotalAmt" > </span>        </td>
        <td> <select data-bind = "options:$parent.availabeStates,value:Status" > </select>        </td>
        </tr>
</script>
<table id="prod-grid" data-bind="kendoGrid: { data: Products, height: 480,
    sortable: true,useKOTemplates:true,rowTemplate: 'rowTemplate',

    columns: [ 
    { field: 'ProdName', title : 'Product Name'}, 
    { field: 'UnitCost', title: 'Unit Cost'}, 
    { field: 'TotalAmt', title: 'Batch Total'},
    { field:'Status', title: 'Status'}]
}"></table>
<div data-bind="foreach:Products">
<span data-bind="text:ProdName"></span>

</div>

var vm = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.Products = ko.observableArray();
    self.availabeStates = ['Fulfilled', 'Pending']
    self.init = function () {
        self.Products.push({
            ProdName: 'Prod1',
            UnitCost: 200,
            TotalAmt: 400,
            Status: 'Fulfilled'
        });
        self.Products.push({
            ProdName: 'Prod2',
            UnitCost: 200,
            TotalAmt: 400,
            Status: 'Pending'
        });

    };
    self.init();
}
ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

here is the JSFiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/dhanasekaran/QqTwU/3/
 I didnt use kendo dropdown purposefully as i had issues with zIndex of drop down, but thats you shall fix and not relevant to this Q/A i guess.